# factory-girl association has_many through with existing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, factory-bot

maybe im not phrasing the question right.

I have a data structure that looks like this

A Facility has many users through a Facility role

now in factory gril I know i can create an association like this

```
factory :facility_role do
  facility {|f| f.association(:facility)}
  user {|u| u.association(:user)}
  role "ABC"
end
```

but what I want is to associate it to the first facility if there is one otherwise call the create like it dose in the code above

Answer (score 1):

you have access to the currently creating object in your blocks. so you can do what you want in your factory. to make things more clear, you should rename f and u to fr for facility_role.

there are also some callbacks that you can hook into: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks